# LInux - Error fatal irrecuperable, abortando:

Tags: linux, ubuntu

recientemente instalé ubuntu 22.04 en mi computadora y he tenido algunos problemas al instalar un paquete, incluso al hacer el apt upgrade.

he investigado e intentado utilizar algunos comandos como

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

el error que obtengo es el siguiente

```
dpkg: error fatal irrecuperable, abortando:
 falta un salto de línea nueva al final del fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `distro-info-data' 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

¿Alguien tendrá alguna idea de porque el error y como resolverlo?

Comment: ¿por qué doble `sudo`?

Comment: al parecer quedo mal instalado, ya probaste reinstalando?